# unsupported addressable value (argument="target") - hardhat@2.19.1 and @openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.0

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat

When I create an OpenZeppelin ERC721 Smart Contract using [OpenZeppelins Smart Contract wizard builder](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#erc721), I get an error when trying to deploy the smart contract to my local network using hardhat. I have tried updating all the modules to the newest version, but still I can't get a basic smart contract working.

Error message:

```
C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project>npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
Compiled 2 Solidity files successfully (evm target: paris).
TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value={  }, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.8.1)
    at makeError (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:687:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:727:5)
    at resolveAddress (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\address\checks.ts:122:19)
    at C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:172:60
    at ParamType.#walkAsync (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:777:24)
    at ParamType.walkAsync (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments.ts:795:24)
    at C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:170:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveArgs (C:\Users\ericb\Desktop\vue-project\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:169:37) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'target',
  value: {},
  shortMessage: 'unsupported addressable value'
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a vue project `npm create vue@latest`. Select all default values.
2. Set up hardhat in the newly created project and select all default values:

```
cd vue-project
npm install --save-dev hardhat @openzeppelin/contracts @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
npx hardhat
```

3. Change the solidity version in `hardhat.config.js` to `0.8.20`.
4. Replace the code in contracts/Lock.sol with the code from the OpenZeppelin contract wizard when `Mintable` is selected from the left menu:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    constructor(address initialOwner)
        ERC721("MyToken", "MTK")
        Ownable(initialOwner)
    {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

5. Replace scripts/deploy.js with:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const lock = await hre.ethers.deployContract("MyToken", []);
  await lock.waitForDeployment();
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

6. Run `npx hardhat node` in one console and `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost` in the other.
7. Smart Contract is expected to be deployed at this point, but instead I get the error message initially provided.

How do I fix this? Or at the very least, how do I better understand the origin of this error? It seems like it doesn't even come from any code that I have written. For example; I haven't used the argument target anywhere that I can see, so how do I understand this error messsage?

npm installs these versions:

```
+-- @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox@4.0.0
+-- @openzeppelin/contracts@5.0.0
+-- @vitejs/plugin-vue@4.5.0
+-- hardhat@2.19.1
+-- vite@4.5.0
`-- vue@3.3.8
```

I appreciate your time reading this.

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you haven't provide the `initialOwner` argument for `MyToken`'s constructor.

you can fix it by add an argument to `deployContract` such as:

```
const lock = await hre.ethers.deployContract("MyToken", ["0x8464135c8F25Da09e49BC8782676a84730C318bC"]);
```